# How to run a python script when I click a button on webpage?

Tags: python, html, node.js, express, face-detection

I made a simple face detection program in python. When you run the file, webcam pops up on the screen and detects your face.
The thing is, I want to run that file on a web page. Let's say I made a simple html file that has a button in it. If you click that button, I want the python script to run, so that the webcam would pop up on the screen and detect me. 
I have developed server with nodejs and express before. What should I use to make that happen? Do i need to use some modules? Or is it only possible if I use Django instead?(Is this a possible option?)Thanks in advance..

Comment: first learn web framework like `Flask`, `Django` or other framework because web pages work very different then console scripts or desktop programs. Desktop program can use only local monitor - so if you will run it on server then pop up window will try to use monitor connected to server, not connected to your local computer, and you will not see this popup window. And it will also use camera assigned to server, not to your local computer.

Comment: To get image from local computer and use on server you will havet to use JavaScript because only web browser will have access to local camera. And you will have to save result in file and display this image in HTML. SO probably you will have to change a lot in your code.